# Why won't my Angular service work correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a service with the following code:

```
angular.module('myApp' , []).
service('facebook' , ['$window' , function(){
return function(){
    alert('hello!')
}
}])
```

and trying to use it in my controller with this code:

```
angular.module('myApp' , [])
.controller('mainControl' , ['$scope' , '$http' , '$log', 'facebook' , function($scope,$http,$log,facebook){
    $scope.$log = $log;
    $scope.message = 'hello world!';
    $scope.callFacebook = function(){
        facebook();
    }
}])
```

But I keep getting this error: 'Unknown provider: facebookProvider <- facebook... This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency.'

I feel like I'm following the documentation to a tee. What am I missing?

Comment: Remove the ,[] from your service app declaration. You only declare app level dependencies once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created twice myApp.

Please see here: http://jsbin.com/bopumo/2/edit

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('facebook' , ['$window' , function($window){
    return function(){
        alert('hello!')
    }
    }])

    app.controller('mainControl' , ['$scope' , '$http' , '$log', 'facebook' , function($scope,$http,$log,facebook){
        $scope.$log = $log;
        $scope.message = 'hello world!';

        $scope.callFacebook = function(){
            facebook();
        }
    }])
```

Comment: This is working correctly when they are in the same file. Thank you for the help. But I'm wondering how I can get them to work on their own in controllers.js and services.js?